# Low Replace inside Low search only finds first occurrence of query

Tags: search, low-search, low-replace, regex

i have a multi-language site setup with low search. every language has it's own collection - this works quite nice. Now i might have been a bit too excited about template partials and let the client fill in a lot of content in which he can insert all sorts of images and other stuff by doing for example "{image_12}"... this tags are now in my search-excerpts as well and i want them gone.

i try to filter them out with low replace but it finds only the first occurrences of my query. my code looks something like this:

```
<ul>
{exp:low_search:results query="{segment_3}" status="not closed" limit="10" disable="member_data"}
        <li>
            <h3><a href="/{language_code}{page_uri}">{bbr-mls:title}</a></h3>
            {exp:low_replace find="\{.*?\}" replace="" regex="yes"}{low_search_excerpt}{/exp:low_replace}
        </li>
{/exp:low_search:results}    
</ul>
```

any help much appreciate (and sorry low for bugging you on twitter - you are right, this is the place to ask.)

cheers, moritz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example actually worked fine in a test I did. But it could be that the curly brackets are encoded to entities, so the regex doesn't actually match. You could try this:

```
{exp:low_replace find="(\{|&#123;)[\w\-]+?(\}|&#125;)" regex="yes"}
    {low_search_excerpt}
{/exp:low_replace}
```

If you're just filtering out those image tags, you could also consider wrapping the Low Replace tag around the whole Low Search Results tag:

```
{exp:low_replace find="(\{|&#123;)image_\d+(\}|&#125;)" regex="yes"}
    {exp:low_search:results ... }
        ...
    {/exp:low_search:results}
{/exp:low_replace}
```

Comment: the better regex worked right away. thank you!